# Conditionally Enforce Exception Handling

Tags: java

I have a method which under certain conditions may throw an exception, but most of the time will not. I would like to require anyone who calls this method to catch the exception if they call it under the "dangerous" conditions, but not have to worry about it under "safe" conditions.

```
public static boolean dangerousSituation; // set somewhere else

public sometimesDangerousMethod() throws MyException {
// some code 
// may throw MyException if dangerousSituation == true
// will never throw MyException if dangerousSituation == false
}

otherMethod() {
    dangerousSituation = false;
    sometimesDangerousMethod(); // shouldn't have to worry about MyException
                                  // if it can't possibly happen
    dangerousSituation = true;
    try {
        sometimesDangerousMethod(); // should be required to handle
                                      // MyException if it may possibly happen
    } catch(MyException e) {
        // handle MyException
    }
}
```

That is, I would like to require a try/catch block around sometimesDangerousMethod() if and only if dangerousSituation == true.

The reason I want this is because I don't want to bother developers with exception handling if they stick to safe situations anyway. But of course, if a developer does use a dangerous situation, the compiler should let him know.

Is there some way to get this behavior in Java?

I have considered breaking up sometimesDangerousMethod() into two methods: one dangerous, one safe. But I don't think this makes sense since this would require developers to be aware of two methods which do basically the same thing.

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to mix runtime state (i.e. whether a variable is `true` or `false`) with compile-time checks (i.e. checked exceptions).  That isn't going to work :/  I suggest you create "safe" and "unsafe" versions of your method.

Comment: Sounds like two different functions to me.

Comment: *"this would require developers to be aware of two methods which do basically the same thing"* -- As opposed to requiring developers to be aware of the implementation details of your method regarding the dangerous situation?

Comment: @Benitok This is my personal opinion, so I didn't include it in my answer, but I would say it is much more reasonable for another developer to be aware of the existence of a second method than it is for them to understand what constitutes a `dangerousSituation`.

Comment: I would suggest creating a DangerousSituationCalledException class and have it be thrown when the dangerous thing fails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The functionality you're looking for doesn't exist. You can either split it into two methods, or your coworkers will have to use a try-catch. Sorry, but sometimes the answer is just "No".

Comment: In this case the answer isn't no though. Using a `RuntimeException` would allow the callers to ignore any exception handling, so it's possible. Of course it's not good design and not a proper solution for this case, but it's not impossible.

Comment: Yes, that's a third option.  But this answer is still basically correct - you can't inform compile-time checks with runtime info.

Answer (score 2):

@mypetlion is accurate on the most part. 
There are a couple of other options for you to consider is:

1. Would it be possible to handle the exception inside of `sometimesDangerousMethod()` instead of `otherMethod()`? If so, then you could pass in the logging/metric object to the method, `try/catch` inside of the method, and log an error message or update a metric when this occurs. This way, you don't have to worry about `try/catch` in the case that the exception doesn't occur.
2. You could break it up into 2 methods like @mypetlion mentioned and with a bit of organization, it may be good enough code:

`

```
public class Solution {
  public static boolean dangerousSituation; // set somewhere else

  public void notDangerousMethod(){
    // will never throw MyException
  }

  public void dangerousMethod() throws MyException {
    // throws MyException 
  }

  public void sometimesDangerousMethod() throws MyException {
    if(dangerousSituation){
      dangerousMethod();
    } else {
      notDangerousMethod();
    }
  }

  public void otherMethod() {
    dangerousSituation = false;

    // Option 1:
    if(dangerousSituation){
      try{
        dangerousMethod();
      } catch(MyException e) {
          // handle MyException
      }
    } else {
      notDangerousMethod();
    }

    // Option 2:
    try {
        sometimesDangerousMethod(); // should be required to handle
                                    // MyException if it may possibly happen
    } catch(MyException e) {
        // handle MyException
    }

}
```

`

Depending on contents of sometimesDangerousMethod(), this may be overkill. If it is a few very simple lines of logic, it might be worth it to implement your original design. I don't think the developers would mind :)

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the point of the word Exception.  Your code should not throw an `Exception` unless *there is an exceptional situation*.  Properly designed code that consumes your code still needs to handle the possibility of an exceptional situation.

Comment: I think the OP understands this.  They're saying that in some situations, their code/method can *never* throw an exception.

Comment: Thanks @OliverCharlesworth - I understand that but it's a bad requirement - if the method could possibly throw the exception then the user of the code needs to deal with it. If I open a file I know exists then I shouldn't have to worry about a `IOException` but should there be two versions of every method?  That would be a really bad design.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't worry so much about the users of your method having to worry about exceptions.

If your method can fail for whatever reason, it should declare the exception (or use an unchecked exception) and throw the exception if it really fails. That's exactly what exceptions are for.

So I think `dangerousSituation` is in fact a very dangerous flag. In the code you propose, setting the flag translates to "do not tell me if the method fails [because I know better than the method's implementation that there will not be a failure]".

So, the only reason for not throwing can be a method that will surely succeed. And any decent Java developer should know how to handle exceptions (typically by letting them pass through to a top level where all exceptions are caught and logged).